# Как убрать первый пробел в инпуте, когда условие сработало?

Tags: javascript, html

Я хочу убрать первый пробел в инпуте, когда сработало условие нажатия на пробел.

Как это сделать?

```js
let inp = document.getElementById("in");
function hendler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        inp.value = null;
        inp.value.trim();
    }
}
inp.addEventListener('keydown', hendler, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присвоить инпуту новое значение

```js
let inp = document.getElementById("in");
function hendler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32) {
        inp.value = inp.value.trim();
    }
}
inp.addEventListener('keydown', hendler, false);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" >
```

Comment: не работает, я уже решил задачу с помощью event.preventDefault();

Comment: А здесь - работает